# How to export schema in graphql nexus framework in version 0.20+?

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql

In many examples in:

https://github.com/graphql-nexus/schema

There are defined parameters like:

- `shouldGenerateArtifacts`
- `outputs`

in function `makeSchema`.

But after update to `0.20` in docs there is changed workflow connected with `makeSchema` and I can't find any example of exporting text version of schema.

https://www.nexusjs.org/#/getting-started/migrate-from-nexus-schema?id=using-nexusschema

I looking for command that will create text schema of graphql

Now I can get it only manually by downloading form

```
localhost:4000
```

[image]